# Buttons not lining up at the same height because of text above it when resizing window

Tags: html, css

I've "improved" my coding skills thanks to the internet over the couple of days. But sometimes, I still run into some problems. Bascially, I got text and under the text I got buttons. And ofcourse, some paragraphs are longer than the others. So when I resize the window, some buttons will be moved lower than the others. And when it moves too low, bad things happen. Have a look at my code to get a better understanding:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
        <title>Galaxy</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <style type="text/css">
</style>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div id="theCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="images/galaxy3.jpg">
                        <div class="slide1"></div>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <div class="bannertext">
                                <h1>Santorodesign</h1>
                                <p>A website made by Michael</p>
                                <a href="indexdutch.html"><button id="headerbutton-language-dutch">Nederlands</button></a>
                                <a href="index.html"><button id="headerbutton-language-english">English</button></a>
                            </div>      
                        </div>                  
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="slide2"></div>
                        <img src="images/galaxy2.jpg">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <div class="bannertext2">
                                <h1>Explore the galaxy<h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>          
                </div>

                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                </a>

                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> 
                </a>            
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="planets">
            <div class="planettext">
                Planets
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/mercury.png"> <br>
                    <p>Mercury is the smallest and innermost planet in the Solar System. 
                    Its orbital period around the Sun of 88 days is the shortest of 
                    all the planets in the Solar System. It is named after the Roman 
                    deity Mercury.</p>
                <a href=""><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about Mercury</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/earth.png"> <br>
                    <p>Earth, known as the World or the Globe, is the third planet from the Sun
                    and the only object in the Universe known to harbor life. It is the densest
                    planet in the Solar System and the largest of the four terrestrial planets.</p>
                <a href="#" id="button"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about the Earth</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/venus.png"> <br>
                    <p>Venus is the second planet from the Sun, orbiting it every 224.7 Earth days.
                    It has the longest rotation period (243 days) of any planet in the Solar 
                    System and rotates in the opposite direction to most other planets.</p>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about Venus</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/mars.png"> <br>
                    <p>Mars is the fourth planet from the Sun and the second-smallest planet in the Solar System.
                    Named after the Roman god of war, it is often referred to as the "Red Planet" because the
                    iron oxide prevalent gives it a reddish appearance.</p>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about Mars</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/jupiter.png"><br>
                    <p>Jupiter is the fifth planet from the Sun and the largest in the Solar System. It's a giant planet 
                    with a mass one-thousandth that of the Sun, but two and a half times that of all the other planets 
                    in the Solar System.</p>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about jupiter</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/saturn.png"><br>
                    <p>Saturn is the sixth planet from the Sun and the second-largest in the Solar System.
                       It is a gas giant with an average radius about nine times that of Earth.
                       Saturn is named after the Roman god of agriculture</p>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about Saturn</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/uranus.png"><br>
                    <p>Uranus is the seventh planet from the Sun. It has the third-largest planetary radius 
                       and fourth-largest planetary mass in the Solar System. It is the coldest planetary atmosphere 
                       in the Solar System.</p>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about Uranus</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/neptune.png"><br>
                    <p>Neptune is the eighth and farthest known planet from the Sun in the Solar System.
                       Neptune is 17 times the mass of Earth. Neptune orbits the Sun once every 164.8
                       years at an average distance of 30.1 astronomical units.</p>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about Neptune</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <hr class="style-one">
                <div class="plutotext">
                    Pluto
                </div>
                <img src="images/pluto.png"> <br>
                <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more about Pluto</button></a>
                <hr class="style-one">
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
     html {
        margin: 0;
    }

    body {
        background: #DCDCDC;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
        background-image: none;
        width: 10%;
    }

    hr.style-one {
        border: 0;
        height: 1px;
        background: #333;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ccc, #333, #ccc);
    }

    .bannertext {
         font-size: 1.3em;
         line-height: 15px;
         position: relative;
    }
        .bannertext h1 {
            font-size: 2em;
        }

    #headerbutton-language-english {
         font-weight: bold;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        color: white;
        background-color: #778899;
        width: 110px;
        text-align: center;  
        border: white 2px solid ;
        line-height: 40px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 50px;
        bottom: 0px;
    }

    #headerbutton-language-dutch {
         font-weight: bold;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        color: white;
        background-color: #778899;
        width: 110px;
        text-align: center;  
        border: white 2px solid ;
        line-height: 40px;
        position: absolute;
        right: -100px;
        bottom: 0px;

    }

    .planettext {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        color: #000;
        margin-top: 200px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #DCDCDC;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .planets {
       font-size: 2em;
       padding: 0px 0 0 0;
       width: 100%;
       text-align: center;
       color: black;
    }
        .planets img {
            height: 300px;
            max-width: none;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }

        .planets button {
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }


    .plutotext {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        color: #000;
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        width: 100%;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 00;
    }

    @media all and (max-width: 960px) {
        #headerbutton-language-dutch { display: none; }
        #headerbutton-language-english { display: none; }
    }

    .mobileShow { display: none;}
    .mobileHide { display: inline;}
         /* Smartphone Portrait and Landscape */
        @media only screen
            and (max-device-width : 480px){
            .mobileShow { display: inline;}
            .mobileHide { display: none;}
            .planet img{
                height: 200px;
            }
        }
```

(I understand that there are some mistakes here and there, I'm new to this, sorry.) But I do understand why this is happening, because the button and the paragraphs are in the same div. I tried setting a min-height to the buttons. It works, but it doesn't look nice at all. What I want is for the 3 (or 2 buttons, depending on the window size) to be set at the same height as the one with the longest paragraph at that time. Is anyone willing to talk some sense into me and help me figure this out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this out https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin-bottom.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I have something that will work. I encourage you to learn about Flexbox. It's a very powerful tool! Below are the adjustments that I've made to your CSS:

```
.planets {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 0px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.planets .col-lg-4 a{
    height: 48px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.planets .col-lg-4{
  padding-bottom: 48px;
}
```

I simply added flexbox properties to the `.planet` styles that already existed. In addition, I added styles for the `<a>` containing your button and the `.col-lg-4` `<div>` element. Lastly, I did remove the margin-bottom for the `<button>` element. See it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/qrc05fsk/

Comment: Wow, I didn't knew flexbox could be this useful.
I'll definitely take the time to learn about them. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Michael Sure thing. Let me know if you run into any trouble.